# how to get values parts from scala without using two for loops?

Tags: scala

I have scala code below and want to get value parts
but the problem is there are nested for loops as you see below:

```
var result: Set[String]()
val mapValues: Map[String, Set[String]]  =  ...

// this returns Iterable[Set[String]] instead of Set[String], 
// so I had to use two for loops as you see below.
val values: Iterable[Set[String]] = mapValues.values   

for( value <- values) { // problem: this is two for loops which is not good
  for(v <- value) {
    result.add(v)
  }
}
```

In java terms, this is what I want:

```
Set<String> result = ...
Map<String, Set<String>> mapValues = ...

Set<String> values = mapValues.values();
for(String value: values) {
   result.add(value);
}
```

want to get the values of mapValues which is Set part and 
put it in the result set variable.

But I don't know how to do it in Scala without using two for loops above.

Comment: `val result = mapValues.values.fold(Set())(_++_)`

Answer (score 1):

You can combine the two for-loops into one:

```
for (value <- values; v <- value) {
  result.add(v)
}
```

Or call `.flatten` on the nested collection:

```
for (v <- values.flatten) {
  result.add(v)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use only one loop and use `union` method of `Set`.

```
for( value <- values) { 
    result = result.union(value)
}
```